# converting MYSQL code into oracle sql code

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below mentioned is the code in MYSQL. I was wondering if there is a way to convert the code into oracle. It would be really helpful if an explanation is given what is the meaning of this statement `(countofzones AS CHAR charset utf8)`

```
CAST(countofzones AS CHAR charset utf8) AS countofzones,
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, `CAST()` converts data of one type to another type. In the example given, you are converting the column `countofzones` from whatever datatype it currently has to the `CHAR` type (with the `utf8` characterset). The `AS countofzones` is simply an alias and is not relevant to the question. See [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) for further information.

The equivalent function in Oracle is named the same; [`CAST()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) and has very similar syntax.

```
CAST(countofzones AS CHAR(x))
```

where `x` is the maximum string length (see [CHAR Datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1821)).

Comment: there is no need of charset utf8  when i change the query to oracle?

Comment: Without more context I can't tell you if it's needed. It will default to the database characterset, which is generally what you should be using anyway. If you do need to specify the charset, you can use [`CONVERT()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620).